# make nohup ignore ">" and "<"

Tags: terminal, nohup

So, i'm running moses machine translation system on my server computer. I access terminal from ssh, and i came across an interesting problem.

The scrip i'm running uses > to specify and output file and it looks like this:

```
~/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f /home/tin/working/filtered/moses.ini -i /home/tin/working/filtered/input.29242 > final
```

Now, since it will take some time for the translation to finish (around 10 hours) i want it to run with nohup, but when i do that even if i put & at the end i end up with file named "final" filled with stdout stuff.

Any idea on how to avoid it??

Comment: `ln -s /dev/null final` before running? That will discard the output; I'm not really sure that this is what you're after. Assuming the redirects are in the script which you run using nohup - nohup doesn't even process them, it just protects the shell which runs the script from being terminated by SIGHUP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the commands inside an actual script file, you could get rid of the `>` inside the script, and run `nohup ./sciptname.sh`.

This will print the script's output to terminal, but nohup will redirect it to "nohup.out" in the current directory.

Source:

According to the nohup manpage I am reading, `If the standard output is a terminal, the standard output is appended to the file nohup.out in the current directory.`

Give it a shot :)